# RegEx select whole string but omit substring match

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Consider a long *html* string: I need to have the whole content without certain tags sections.

**Example:**

Consider the following string:

```
;decreasing'>1</a>&nbsp;<span class='active'>2</span><a href='&#2;F;search&
```

I need to select **all but the span section**, thus **removing the following**

```
<span class='active'>2</span>
```

and ending up with only the following

```
;decreasing'>1</a>&nbsp;<a href='&#2;F;search&
```

I tried the following with negative look behind selections in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) but no luck.

```
^(?!=(<span class='active'>(.*?)<\/span>)).*$
```

**[Additional Info]**

If I could combine the two following selections it would solve the problem:

> 1.Selects everything up to the *span* tag

```
.*?(?=<span)
```

> 2. Selects everything from the *closing span* tag onward:

```
(?<=span>).*
```

Thanks your help in advance.

Comment: What language/environment will you be running this pattern in?

Comment: Why do not you do a simple `replace` and then **print** `perl -lpe 's/<span.*?span>//g' file`

Answer (score 0):

If your coding language permits you to do a regex split or replace call, you can use this pattern:

`~<(span).*?(/\1)>~` or expand your tag list like this: `~<(span|div).*?(/\1)>~`

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/DnRJ1n/1)

There are risks involved in processing html with regex patterns, but they may or may not come into play depending on the structure of your html.

Comment: If my method is not suitable for any reason, please leave me a comment and consider improving your question.

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, thanks for the suggestion but if I am not wrong your regex selects the text I need to eliminate. What I need to do is select all the remaining text with exception of that.

Comment: @polarized That's why I am suggesting that you use this with a split or replace function.  What language are you using?

Comment: Hi, I need to use it with the screen-scraper program to create a sub-extractor pattern. As the position of the <span> tag section constantly changes across the multiple pages being scraped, I need to ignore it and consider only the rest of the string. Unfortunately I cannot use a replace function, only RegEx. I managed to do it once but really cannot remember the solution. :-(

Comment: @polarized What is the name of the screen-scraper program?